New to GKE and helm. How to get access to aerokube/moon2 installed using helm and kubeclt?
I am new to kubernetes, and helm
I have a GKE cluster. I created a GCE VM to act as the master for aerokube. Connected it to the GKE cluster. I installed aerokube/moon2 using this as a guide: https://aerokube.com/moon/latest/#install-kubernetes
The install uses a helm chart and kubectl to install.
I have the service installed.
kubectl get svc -n moon
NAME   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
moon   ClusterIP   34.118.XXX.xxx   \<none\>        4444/TCP,9090/TCP,8080/TCP   30h

My issue is how do I connect to it from an external server.
The service seems to be up. The IP is internal.
I have not been able to get anything connected to the service.
helm seems to say that ingress is setup:
$ helm show values aerokube/moon2
ingress:
enabled: true
host: moon.aerokube.local
ingressClassName: nginx

I have tried creating a load balancer with a network endpoint group. I don't see a public or exposed IP that I should point to. The service is running on a container, and not exposed to the OS. Port 8080 is not listening at the OS level, but is being used.
I am able to hit the VM on other ports. The goal is to expose a public IP so that jenkins can submit test jobs to it.
What am I missing?
